# Is there some downsides in the use Fragments as a logged users instance?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-activity, firebase-authentication

Hello I am using Firebase and when the user logs in I want to send the to their home user page, but I don't know if it is better or more secure o anything else to use activities in preferences of fragments.

I've been watching many tutorials in a lot of them they use activities over fragments?

And they didn't explain why. Is there some advantage of the use of activities over fragments in this task?

Comment: Since you are using Firestore, I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) will help. Here is the [auth](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth) package.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you Alex !!

Comment: @AlexMamo Hey, Alex I've been watching the code of the github code, and I noticed that you use singleton, I am not very familiar with dagger, and inject. Could I just use companion object class as an equivalent for singleton?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.